# map reduce program throws arrayindex out of bound error

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am very new to MapReduce model. I am trying to read multiple files who are separated first by colon (unique id)  and then some comma separated info like (cust id, int value). I want to parse all files and aggregate all cust id and int value corresponding to unique id in output file. I am getting some array index out of bound and also I am not aware how to parse all files with my code. should i use tokenizer to iterate through values or Map functions already does that? My code looks like:

```
public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
int rating = 0;
Text CustID;
IntWritable r;
Text MovieID;
public void map(LongWritable key, Text line, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line1 = line.toString();
        String [] fields = line1.split(":");
        String Movieid = fields[0];
        String line2 = fields[1];
        String [] splitline = line2.split(",");
        String Custid = splitline[0];
        int rate = Integer.parseInt(splitline[1]);
        r = new IntWritable(rate);
        CustID.set(Custid);
        MovieID.set(Movieid);
        context.write(MovieID,r);
```

Modified code As per BlackSmith suggestions, Thanks Blacksmith for all your help. However I am still getting empty output file. Kindly suggest.

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text line, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line1 = line.toString();
        String [] fields = line1.split(":");
        if(fields.length > 1)
             {
             String Movieid = fields[0];
             String line2 = fields[1];
             String [] splitline = line2.split(",");
             String Custid = splitline[0];
             int rate = Integer.parseInt(splitline[1]);
             r = new IntWritable(rate);
             CustID = new Text(Custid);
             MovieID = new Text(Movieid);
             context.write(MovieID,r);
             }
             else
             {
             return;
             }
             }
          }
        public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  for (IntWritable val : values) {
    context.write(key, val);
    }}}
```

Can I write anything on console to see why my output file is generated, but its empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens due to presence of bad records. Your `map` is expecting an input like the following :

```
Matrix:Reeves,5
```

But the input file somewhere contains a record without both these characters `:` & `,`. An empty line may be the culprit. All you need is length checks for the splits arrays. Instead of access indices directly, put them inside a validation block. eg :

```
String [] fields = line1.split(":");
if( fields.length>1 ){     
    String Movieid = fields[0];
    String line2 = fields[1];
} else {
    // initialize Movieid & line2 tosome default value
    // OR simply put a 'return' statement to skip bad inputs  
}
```

Same strategy has to be followed for the `splitline` array. I think you don't need codes for that. Again don't use `StringTokenizer`, it's still in existence due to legacy reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot BlackSmith. its working now but generating and empty file. can you please suggest what should be my reduce function as for my 1st step I just want output of Map. I am trying below code but its giving error:                             public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      context.write(key, values);}

Comment: `job.setNumReduceTask(0)` to remove reduce phase. But your problem is that you'r trying to write an Iterable rather than IntWritable to the context. Use `for(IntWritale val : values) { context.write(key, val);}`

Answer (score -1):

I just solved issue by placing all the code inside below condition

```
if(input.toString().length() > 0)
{
    <code>
}
```